# Meteor Iron Router, Pub Sub causing weird behavior

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, iron-router

I am trying to make sing post page a route where it does a several things using iron:router

1. Uses the template `postPage`
2. Subscribes to publication of `singlePost`, `userStatus` (shows status and info of Author of single post page'), `comments` .
3. Grabs `Comments` documents that has field of `postId : this.params._id`
4. Increments Comments List by `Session.get('commentLimit')`

Here is the code I currently have.

---

**Router.js**

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  subscriptions: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('singlePost', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('userStatus'),
      Meteor.subscribe('comments', {
        limit: Number(Session.get('commentLimit'))
      })
    ];
  },
  data: function() {
    return Posts.findOne({_id:this.params._id});
   },
});
```

---

**Publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('singlePost', function(id) {
  check(id, String);
  return Posts.find(id);
});

Meteor.publish('comments', function(options) {
  check(options, {
    limit: Number
  });
  return Comments.find({}, options);
});
```

---

**Template.postPage.onCreated**

```
Template.onCreated( function () {
  Session.set('commentLimit', 4);
});
```

**Template.postPage.helpers**

```
Template.postPage.helpers({
    comments: function () {
      var commentCursor = Number(Session.get('commentLimit'));
      return Comments.find({postId: this._id}, {limit: commentCursor});
    },
});
```

**Template.postPage.events**

```
Template.postPage.events({
    'click a.load-more-comments': function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Session.set('commentLimit', Number(Session.get('commentLimit')) + 4)
    }
});
```

---

Everything works fine, but I found one thing to be inconsistent.
Here is the problem I am having...

1. User goes into single post page and adds comment (everything works fine).
2. User goes into a different single post page and adds comment (everything works fine).
3. **Here is where the problem begins**

   - The user at any time, goes into another route that is not the single post page.
4. User goes back into single post page

   - The comments are not showing.
   - New comments will be added into DB but still wont show
5. This problem only goes away when `meteor reset` or manual deletion of all comments in MongoDB is performed.

Is there a better way that I can code my routing and related code to stop this weird behavior from happening?

Or even if there is a better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your publish is publishing comments without any `postId` filter.

Your helper, filters by `postId`. Maybe the 4 comments that get published are the ones that do not belong to the current post that is open?

Could you try updating, your subscription to

```
Meteor.subscribe('comments', {
    postId: this.params._id
}, {
    limit: Number(Session.get('commentLimit'))
})
```

and your publication to

```
Meteor.publish('comments', function(filter, options) {
    check(filter, {
        postId: String
    });
    check(options, {
        limit: Number
    });
    return Comments.find(filter, options);
});
```

so that only the same posts' comments are published?

Comment: My intention was to show 4 comments whenever page is renavigated/refreshed/reloaded etc. Using `Session.set(value+4)` was to show more comments.

Comment: It's no problem. I am using a subscription GUI and it's returning any comments from any posts... Maybe is there a way I could tweak some code so that Meteor only publishes comments for `this.params._id` or `this._id`?

Comment: I chose your answer as the correct one because I think it's better practice to structure it this way for readability and scalibility!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I have updated the following codes.

So far it is not showing weird behavior...

**Publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('comments', function(postId, limit) {
  check(postId, String);
  check(limit, Number);
  return Comments.find({postId:postId}, {limit:limit});
});
```

**Router.js**

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  subscriptions: function () {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('singlePost', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('userStatus'),
      Meteor.subscribe('comments', this.params._id, Number(Session.get('commentLimit')))
    ];
  },
  data: function() {
    return Posts.findOne({_id:this.params._id});
   },
});
```

Comment: Yup, I've edited the answer with something similar :)